# AS3: Classloading order

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, avm2

I had a quick question on static blocks in AS3.

I have a library that requires initialization statically before any application logic is executed. If I insert a static code block like the following, will this truly be executed before everything else? (ie: is it *safe* to assume that everything will be setup before the application starts?)

```
package {

    import com.tkassembled.library.MyStaticLibrary;
    import com.tkassembled.library.MyWorker;

    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Application extends Sprite {

        // begin static code 
        /* initialize */ {
            MyStaticLibrary.worker = new MyWorker();
        }

        public function Application() {

        }
    }
}
```

I would assume that the above code would execute in the following fashion:

1. Load `Application` class, as it is the 'main executable'.
2. Load `MyStaticLibrary` and `MyWorker`, executing any static blocks in them.
3. Execute the static blocks within `Application`.
4. Call the constructor and get things going.

Does anyone know if this is true or not? I guess I'll build an application to test it all out in the meantime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did the homework, here is the execution order:

```
[16] Application static block executed.
[16] MyLibrary static blocks invoked. 
[16] MyWorker static blocks
[16] MyWorker constructor called. 
[16] MyLibrary.worker set.
[17] Application constructor executed.
```

It really helps to understand how things work :)

You can get my experiment files here: http://bit.ly/aKwqp6